# git checkout 'branch ' displays error error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:

Tags: git, bitbucket

I'm stuck with git warning: error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout: .idea/misc.xml.
In the first place, I don't know why the previous developer has added the .idea folder into git tracking as all tutorials suggest not to do that.
My situation:
My active repo is "develop"
I want to checkout to feature branch (error displayed)

```
git checkout feature/myBranch
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:
        .idea/misc.xml
Please commit your changes or stash them before you switch branches.
Aborting
```

```
git status
On branch develop
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/develop'.
nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

```
git stash
No local changes to save
```

The problematic file is included to the list assume unchanged:

```
git ls-files -v|grep '^h'
h .idea/misc.xml
```

How to get out of situation?

Answer (score 0):

Rename your `.idea` first,

```
mv .idea .idea_bak
```

Checkout the branch,

```
git checkout feature/myBranch
```

Remove `.idea` from the branch and add it to `.gitignore`,

```
git rm -rf .idea
echo .idea >> .gitignore
git add .gitignore
git commit
```

You could also remove it from the entire history with the help of `git filter-branch` or other history-rewritten tools.

Rename `.idea_bak` back,

```
mv .idea_bak .idea
```

Comment: Thanks!
This helped me out.
But overall, how to deal with the situation then the lead developer has added the .idea directory into the git remote repo. I want it to leave into the remote repo, but I want that my local repo will ignore any changes inside the .idea directory?